# Как отправить сообщение по протоколу tcp/ip всем пингующимся компьютерам на с# ?

Tags: c#, ip, tcp-ip

Как отправить сообщение по протоколу tcp/ip всем пингующимся компьютерам на с#?
Есть одна программа, работающая не нескольких компах, одному из них нужно отправить всем остальным свой ip. 
Или есть другой способ обмены ip адресами?

Comment: @Андрей Анфилец, для успешной отправки tcp сообщения на принимающем компьютере должна быть запущена программа, которая готова его принять. 

Более конкретно, она должна нужным образом слушать известный Вам порт. 

Вообще-то "пинговаться" может оооочень много компьютеров (например 8.8.8.8 (один из адресов google)) и он успешно "пингуется".

В локальной сети можно отправить так называемое broadcast UDP сообщение на определенный порт всех компьютеров. Но "слушатель" все равно должен быть запущен.

Если Вам действительно надо сделать нечто **конкретное**, то опишите свою задачу поподробнее.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользоваться интерфейсом [IShellItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx) с KNOWNFOLDERID [CSIDL_NETWORK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx).

Можно взять готовую библиотеку на [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gong-shell/).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GongSolutions.Shell;
using GongSolutions.Shell.Interop;

public sealed class ShellNetworkComputers : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ShellItem folder = new ShellItem((Environment.SpecialFolder)CSIDL.NETWORK);
        IEnumerator<ShellItem> e = folder.GetEnumerator(SHCONTF.FOLDERS);

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            Debug.Print(e.Current.ParsingName);
            yield return e.Current.ParsingName;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Нагуглено [оттуда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557551/how-get-list-of-local-network-computers).

P.S.: Подразумеваю, что отправка и прием данных через сокеты проблемой не является.